# Conditional task based on template parameter fails

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to use Ansible to deploy to two regions in AWS, I have it working with one region at the moment. The issue is I want to only execute my `primary_region` or my `secondary_region` depending on the parameter from the template it's using.

My `main.yaml`:

```
- hosts: primary_region
  name: Create ECR
  tasks:
    - name: "Create ECR Repository"
      cloudformation:
        state: "{{ state }}"
        stack_name: "{{ stack_create_ecr.name }}"
        profile: "{{ aws_profile }}"
        region: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        template_url: "{{ stack_create_ecr.template_url }}"
        template_parameters:
          "ansibleFile"
        tags:
          "{{ stack_create_ecr.tags }}"
      tags:
        - stack_create_ecr
      when: stack_create_ecr.region == "primary_region" <-- This
        
- hosts: secondary_region
  name: Create ECR
  tasks:
    - name: "Create ECR Repository"
      cloudformation:
        state: "{{ state }}"
        stack_name: "{{ stack_create_ecr.name }}"
        profile: "{{ aws_profile }}"
        region: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        template_url: "{{ stack_create_ecr.template_url }}"
        template_parameters:
          "ansibleFile"
        tags:
          "{{ stack_create_ecr.tags }}"
      tags:
        - stack_create_ecr
      when: stack_create_ecr.region == "secondary_region" <-- This
```

The template that I am using
`stack_create_ecr.yaml`:

```
stack_create_ecr:
  name: cloudFormationTemplateNameOmitted
  template_url: S3BucketUrl
  parameters:
    RepoName: EcrRepoName
    DevName: cloud-dev
  tags:
    ansible_playbook: "{{ ansible_playbook_tag }}"
  region: primary_region <-- This is what I'm trying to use
```

Everytime I try to run my playbook I just get `msg: 'argument template_parameters is of type <class ''str''> and we were unable to convert to dict: dictionary requested, could not parse JSON or key=value'`

I have tried all sorts of things from putting quotes around the string in the `when` condition. Nothing seems to work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [`template_parameters` parameter for module `cloudformation`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/cloudformation_module.html#parameter-template_parameters) expects a dictionary or a key=value string type. You are passing a simple string (i.e. `"ansibleFile"`). Your error message tells you exactly what I just rephrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you massed up with `template_parameters` prop. It should be a map but you provided a string:

```yaml
        template_parameters:
          PropName: "ansibleFile"
```